# Redirect ONLY on SSL request to another domain MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure whether this can be acheived in code or if this rule needs to be applied within ISS.

Basically I have three domains:

```
domain1.co.uk > redirects to .com
domain1.com > Primary domain registered with SSL
domain1.ie > I want to redirect this to .com based on SSL request
```

I have configured my MVC app to display relative content based on the domain. So if the request comes in from a .ie address then I can then display relevant content/Meta data etc. However my issue is that when I visit /Account/Login under HTTPS I get an SSL error as the certificate is registered under the .com domain.

I would really like to keep the .ie binding for the HTTP static site and index this on Google but as soon as the user tries to navigate to a HTTPS I would like to switch to the .com domain.

I appreciate I can do this by changing the links throughout the site and I have also tried the below with no avail:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if(Context.Request.IsSecureConnection && Context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("domain1.ie"))
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("domain1.ie", "domain1.com"));
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, even with a redirect in place the browser must first access the SSL site on the `.ie` domain so the web server can send the redirect. As such they will still receive an invalid certificate error.

As such the best option here is to change the links in the site, otherwise you'd have to get an SSL certificate for the `.ie` site.

As for the actual redirect, This can be handled this directly in IIS, set up a binding for SSL only on `.ie` domain separate from the main website. Set the physical path to an empty directory (it won't be serving any content). Then set a http redirect for all requests with 301 permanent.

[image: IIS 7 redirect]